# How to use Errordocument 404 with 301 in header?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a dynamic content website and I want to redirect all non existed pages to index page but with the header showing 301 permanent redirect and not the 404 error.

I know that I can redirect with .htaccess

```
Errordocument 404 /index.php
```

But this will have the 404 status in the header, and I'd rather the header to show a 301 redirect.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want your website to show a 301, instead of a 404. 404 means that the page can not be found. That's exactly the situation you are describing.

Comment: the thing is thousands of pages are created and removed daily from site so i dont want to loose focus of the surfer by sending them to error page.

Comment: The surfer doesn't care about the 404 status in the header...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't. If some content is not found, the server should return 404; you should only return 301 only if the content has been moved.

That said, it's possible, using the [mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [R=301]
```

This should redirect requests to URIs that aren't files or directories to the index.php, with a 301 header.

But then again, don't. It's guaranteed to confuse human visitors and search engines alike.

Comment: just noticed some pages like www.domain.com/noneeeeeee.html are going to 404 error.

Comment: looks like its the scrips rewrite rule in htaccess causing it.

Comment: Well, it's hard to debug things from a distance, as I know nothing about your site. If you have other rewrite rules in the htaccess, this won't play nice with those. `/index.php` instead of `index.php` may help depending on the location of the htaccess.

Comment: these redirects are used by script. RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^(.*).html$ index.php?qwerty_query=$1.html&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L]